# Ttrigger after insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I'm trying to write trigger which enters a value (+1) into another column.

If I add a new car into the dbo.deelnemers/autonr my dbo.auto's/risico column should be added with the value +1

```
create trigger trRisicos
on deelnemers
after insert
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    declare u/autonr int

    select u/autonr = inserted.autonr
    from inserted

    insert into autos
    values (@autonr, 1)
end
```

This is the code I have so far.

```
dbo.deelnemers/autonr (PK, FK, INT, NOT NULL)
dbo.deelnemers/evenementnr (PK, FK, INT, NOT NULL)

dbo.autos/autonr (PK, INT, NOT NULL)
dbo.autos/typenaam (CHAR(50), NULL)
dbo.autos/bouwjaar (INT, NULL)    
dbo.autos/waarde (INT, NULL)
dbo.autos/passagiers (INT, NULL)
dbo.autos/lidnr (FK, INT, NULL)
dbo.autos/Risico (SMALLINT, NULL)
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Another "question" without a question. Not even an error. I wonder why it appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
create trigger trRisicos
on deelnemers
after insert
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    INSERT INTO autos (autonr, risico)
    SELECT autonr, 1
    FROM INSERTED;
end
```

Comment: I did this, and thanks a lot for it!

Now if I try to add a row into it with "insert into deelnemers (autonr,evenementnr)
values (1,201504)" I get "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'pk_autos'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.autos'. The duplicate key value is (1)."